# PHP Clase para crear formularios HTML: cómo tratar <optgroup>?

Tags: php, html, class

Estoy escribiendo una clase para crear formularios en HTML. Funciona según lo esperado y cumple con el estándar PSR-12 (salvo por unos `warnings` de longitud de línea y 3 errores: camel case para métodos, ausencia del `namespace` para clases y una nueva línea incorrecta `\r\n` en lugar de `\n`).

Contexto:
Para añadir un `<label>`, se hace así:

```
$form->add_field(["label", ["for"=>"mytxtarea", "value"=>"My TXTarea:"]]);
```

Para añadir un `<input>` (`text` en este caso), se puede hacer de cualquiera de estas dos formas:

```
$form->add_field(["text", ["name"=>"mytext", "required"=>true, "value"=>"bool(true)"]]);
$form->add_field(["input", ["type"=>"text", "name"=>"myothertext", "required"=>"cheese tax", "value"=>"cheese tax"]]);
```

En el caso de `<input>` y `<button>` se admite el atributo `type` como pseudo-elemento.

Para añadir un `<select>` hago:

```
$form->add_field(["select",["name"=>"myselect", "selected"=>"value3"], ["value1"=>"text1", "value2"=>"text2", "value3"=>"text3"]]);
```

Y para añadir un `<select>` múltiple:

```
$form->add_field(["select",["name"=>"mymultiselect", "required"=>true, "multiple"=>true, "selected"=>["value3", "value2"]], ["value1"=>"text1", "value2"=>"text2", "value3"=>"text3"]]);
```

Para gestionar el `<select>` uso el siguiente pedazo de código:

```
if ($element == "select") {
        $selected_values = $attributes['selected'] ?? "";

        foreach ($options as $value => $text) {
            $output .= "\n<option value='$value'";

            // simple select
            if (is_string($selected_values) and (strlen($selected_values) != 0) and ($selected_values == $value)) {
                $output .= " selected";
            } elseif (is_array($selected_values) and !empty($selected_values)) { // multiple select
                foreach ($selected_values as $selected) {
                    if ($selected == $value) {
                        $output .= " selected";
                    }
                }
            }

            $output .= ">$text</option>";
        }
    }
```

Sé que debo gestionar la etiqueta `<optgroup>` en este bloque pero no consigo darme cuenta de cómo hacerlo. Si se fijan en la forma de añadir un `<input type="text">`, como dije, el tipo se considera un pseudo-elemento.

Conforme al código que tengo escrito: cómo debería tratar `<optgroup>`?

Graceas!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Con las respuestas de RobertoLeOr y Stack News he conseguido resolver el tratamiento de `<optgroup>` y sus `<options>` con este código:

```
    if ($element == "select") {
        $selected_values = $attributes['selected'] ?? "";

        if ($is_optgroup) { // se establece cuando se verifica el parámetro
            foreach ($options as $label => $opt_grp_options) {
                $output .= "\n<optgroup label='" . $label . "'";

                if (array_key_exists("disabled", $attributes)) {
                    if (in_array($label, $attributes["disabled"])) {
                        $output .= " disabled";
                    }
                }

                $output .= ">";

                foreach ($opt_grp_options as $value => $text) {
                    $output .= "\n<option value='$value'";
                    if (
                        is_string($selected_values) and
                        (strlen($selected_values) != 0) and
                        ($selected_values == $value)
                    ) {
                        $output .= " selected";
                    } elseif (is_array($selected_values)) { // multiple select
                        foreach ($selected_values as $selected) {
                            if ($selected == $value) {
                                $output .= " selected";
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    $output .= ">$text</option>";
                }
                $output .= "</optgroup>";
            }

        } else {

            foreach ($options as $value => $text) {
                $output .= "\n<option value='$value'";

                // simple select
                if (
                    is_string($selected_values) and
                    (strlen($selected_values) != 0) and
                    ($selected_values == $value)
                ) {
                    $output .= " selected";

                } elseif (is_array($selected_values)) { // multiple select/ed

                    foreach ($selected_values as $selected) {
                        if ($selected == $value) {
                            $output .= " selected";
                        }
                    }
                }
                $output .= ">$text</option>";
            }
        }
    }
```

PD: no es el código mas óptimo, pero cumple su función.

Answer (score 1):

**Saludos**

Esperando haber entendido tu planteamiento. Te sugiero hacer uso de clases y funciones PHP. Básicamente para elemento option en select necesitamos un identificador o valor (`value`) y su referencia (`text`); para los `optgroup` necesitamos la forma de identificarlos que es un agrupador así como su texto (`text`) y tener sus hijos (`<option>`).
Con lo anterior mencionado te sugiero crear una clase como la siguiente:

```
class ItemSelect 
{
   public $identificador=0; // 0 para los optgroup
   public $texto; // Leyenda que se muestra
   public $hijos; // Deberá ser un array de tipo ItemSelect 
   
   function __construct() {
      $this->identificador =0;
      $this->texto='';
      $this->hijos=array();
   }

   function toOptionSelect($selected_values) {
      // Sin complicarnos si tiene hijos debe ser optgroup; de lo contrario es option
      $resultado ="";
      if(count($this->hijos)>0)
      {

         $resultado ="<optgroup label=\"".$this->texto."\">";

         foreach ($array as &$valor) {
            $resultado .=$valor.toOptionSelect($selected_values);
         }
         $resultado .="</optgroup>";
      } else {
         $esSeleccionado ="";
         if (is_string($selected_values) and (strlen($selected_values) != 0) and ($selected_values == $value)) {
            $esSeleccionado = " selected";
         } elseif (is_array($selected_values) and !empty($selected_values)) { // multiple select
            foreach ($selected_values as $selected) {
               if ($selected == $value) {
                  $esSeleccionado = " selected";
               }
            }
         }

         $resultado ="<option value=\".$this->identificador .\" ".$esSeleccionado.">".$this->texto."</option>";
      }

      return $resultado;
   }
}
```

Con lo anterior lo que te corresponde es que cada `$options` en tu `foreach ($options as $value => $text)` pasarlo a la clase y crear la estrcutura que  corresponda para poblar como padre o hijo.
De tal forma que una vez realizado quedaria:

```
$lasOpciones = array();
foreach ($options as $value => $text)
{
   // Poblado de $lasOpciones de tal forma que quede agrupado
}

$elementosParaElSelect ="";
foreach ($lasOpciones as &$valor)
{
   $elementosParaElSelect .=$valor.toOptionSelect($selected_values);
}
```

Con lo anterior `$elementosParaElSelect` contendrá los tag `option` y/o `optgroup` para ponerlos al `select` respectivo.

> Importante: tiene tiempo no uso PHP (ni tengo entorno), los foreach pudieran requerir ajustes acorde a la estructura y/o versión que tengas en uso.

Comment: Gracias por el tiempo. Aunque no es la respuesta óptima para adaptar a mi código completo, si fue de gran ayuda.

Answer (score 1):

Para agregar soporte para la etiqueta `<optgroup>` en su código, puede agregar un bloque `if` dentro de su bloque `if` actual que maneja la etiqueta `<select>`. Dentro de este nuevo bloque `if`, puede verificar si la opción actual pertenece a un grupo (usando el atributo `group`) y, de ser así, agregar la etiqueta `<optgroup>` correspondiente antes de la etiqueta `<option>`. Aquí hay un ejemplo de cómo podría hacerlo:

```
if ($element == "select") {
    $selected_values = $attributes['selected'] ?? "";
    $groups = [];

    foreach ($options as $value => $attrs) {
        $text = $attrs['text'] ?? '';
        $group = $attrs['group'] ?? '';
        
        if ($group) {
            $groups[$group][$value] = $text;
        } else {
            $output .= "\n<option value='$value'";
            
            // simple select
            if (is_string($selected_values) and (strlen($selected_values) != 0) and ($selected_values == $value)) {
                $output .= " selected";
            } elseif (is_array($selected_values) and !empty($selected_values)) { // multiple select
                foreach ($selected_values as $selected) {
                    if ($selected == $value) {
                        $output .= " selected";
                    }
                }
            }
            
            $output .= ">$text</option>";
        }
    }

    foreach ($groups as $group => $options) {
        $output .= "\n<optgroup label='$group'>";
        
        foreach ($options as $value => $text) {
            $output .= "\n<option value='$value'";
            
            // simple select
            if (is_string($selected_values) and (strlen($selected_values) != 0) and ($selected_values == $value)) {
                $output .= " selected";
            } elseif (is_array($selected_values) and !empty($selected_values)) { // multiple select
                foreach ($selected_values as $selected) {
                    if ($selected == $value) {
                        $output .= " selected";
                    }
                }
            }
            
            $output .= ">$text</option>";
        }
        
        $output .= "\n</optgroup>";
    }
}
```

En este ejemplo, primero se recorren todas las opciones para determinar si pertenecen a algún grupo, y se separan en un array `$groups`. Luego, se recorre `$groups` para agregar las etiquetas `<optgroup>` y sus opciones correspondientes. El resto del código es esencialmente el mismo que el que ya tenía, pero se ha actualizado para agregar soporte para grupos.

Tenga en cuenta que el ejemplo que he proporcionado es solo una guía, y puede necesitar ajustar su código para que funcione con su implementación específica de la clase de formulario.

Comment: Gracias por el tiempo. Como en la respuesta de RobertoLeOr, no es la solución ótipma para mi código pero he sacado ideas.